# Firebase Crashlytics on Android not persisting user id across app restarts

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

In our app we call `Firebase.crashlytics.setUserId(identifier)` when a user logs in and  `Firebase.crashlytics.setUserId("")` when a user logs out.

This means such methods won't be called across app restarts.
The rationale for this is based on my (possibly wrong) understanding, by briefly looking at the [code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/976ea2fb443bbf7b5828f988275110b6b3b4b281/firebase-crashlytics/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/internal/common/CrashlyticsController.java#L421) , that the SDK is persisting such information to disk.

However I've now noticed that only crash reports that come right after a user has logged in have a user id attached. Whilst any other crash reports that happen after application restarts does not have any user id attached.

Is this a bug?
Is the SDK actually persisting the user id value?
Should I call `Firebase.crashlytics.setUserId(identifier)` on every app startup (e.g. in `Application.onCreate()` ?).

Is there some additional debug I can do?

Comment: I do not think the user id is persisted, so you would want to set it every time on app startup